# Create Function - Gets PLS-00410

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I've been trying to create a function in an Oracle Database but i keep getting this PLS-00410 error, saying that there are double fields in a record or in the table, can anyone help me out?

```
create or replace function lazarus.pro_custo_tot (custo_total in float)
return float
is custo_total float;
begin
    /*Calcula custo unitário * quantidade*/
    select(ed.custo_unitario * ed.quantidade) 
    into custo_total
    from lazarus.estoque_detail ed
    where ED.ID_SABOR = LAZARUS.SABORES.id
    and ED.ID_HEADER = LAZARUS.ESTOQUE_HEADER.id;
    return (custo_total);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because custo_total was defined twice, once in below line 1, and a second time in line 3:

```
create or replace function lazarus.pro_custo_tot (custo_total in float)
return float
is custo_total float;
```

Use different variable names should solve this. However your in parameter does not seem to be needed, since the input value was never referenced.